# Como adicionar +1 em uma variável contadora à cada clique?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cada vez que eu clicar em um botão, quero adicionar +1 a uma variável.

Por exemplo: tenho uma variável `count` recebendo o valor 5, ao clicar em um botão quero que o valor 5 mude para 6 e assim sucessivamente, exibindo em um `alert()`.

É possivel?

Comment: É interessante que você poste um exemplo do que já tentou. Assim podemos te ajudar com sua dúvida de maneira mais interessante. O jsfiddle faz sucesso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seria isto?

HTML:

```
<input type=button id=addCount value="Adicionar Count">
```

Javascript:

```
var count = 5;//recebendo o valor 5 que você disse
$('#addCount').click(function(){
  alert(count);
  count++;
});
```

## [Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suxfd/2/)

Comment: Isso mesmo! Só que assim, no primeiro clique quero seja o proprio numero 5, tem como?

Comment: Claro, é só alterar a posição de onde a `count` é incrementada, veja meu edit.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. Agora deu certo! Obrigado!

Answer (score 9):

Mais uma opção, usando closure. É basicamente o que fez o Paulo Roberto, mas sem variável global:

```
function criaCounter(init) {
    var count = init || 0;
    return function() {
        count++;
        alert(count);
    }
}
// Cria contador que começa em 5, e usa como listener do click
$('#addCount').click(criaCounter(5));
```

Comment: Hum, bacana.. legal! Obrigado.

Comment: Interessante, Porém você está incrementando antes de dar `alert()` por isso o valor `5` não seria alertado, apenas do `6` em diante, certo?

Comment: @PauloRoberto Certo. Dá pra evitar se o corpo da função for `alert(count++)`.

Answer (score 5):

Poderia fazer algo assim:

### HTML

```html
<button id="count" data-valor="5">Clique Aqui!</div>
```

### jQuery

```jquery
$('#count').click( function ( ) {
  var valorVelho = this.data('valor');
  var valorNovo = valorVelho++;
  this.data('valor', valorNovo);
  alert( valorNovo );
} );
```

### Atualização

Sendo que a base é da variável `count`, podeira fazer algo assim:

**HTML**

```
<button id="count">Clique Aqui!</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var count = 5;
$('#count').click( function ( ) {
  count++;
  alert( count );
}
```

Comment: a solução é boa, porém respondendo à pergunta do OP "quero uma variável `count` recebendo o valor 5", sua resposta não estaria dentro do contexto, certo?

Comment: Certo. Não levei em consideração o fato de querer ter a variável `count`.