# Problemas com Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Olá, estou programando meu site no c9.io e estou usando um cont mostrado aqui nesse link: [Como adicionar +1 em uma variável contadora à cada clique?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6580/como-adicionar-1-em-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-contadora-%C3%A0-cada-clique)

porem no c9.io na linha do Js aparece $ is not definied, fix it or add global $. Quando eu tiro o $ nao funciona e quando mantenho n da certo. Como poderia consertar?

```js
var count = 0;
$('#addCount').click(function(){
  alert(count);
  count++;
```

```html
          <input type=button id=addCount value="Adicionar Count">
```

SEGUE O LINK DO SITE https://forum-alldispor.c9users.io/index.html#/topicos

Comment: poderia colocar trechos de códigos?

Comment: Pronto! Obs: estou usando angularjs

Comment: e jQuery??? $ n e do jQuery?

Comment: nao, o $ é depois do var count =0; que esta dando not definied

Comment: Não misture `AngularJS` e `JQuery`. É melhor tentar fazer só com o `AngularJS` ou só com o `JQuery`

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso, agora, você poderia usar database para salvar os likes! Ou um sistema com arquivos!

```js
var like = $("#likes").text();

$("#addLike").click( function() {
  
$("#likes").text(like++);
  
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<h2>Sistema de likes</h2>

<button class="btn" id="addLike">Like</button>

<h1 id="likes">0</h1>
```

Comment: Ainda parece not definied para o $

Comment: Você importou o jQuery???

Comment: Como assim? coloquei tudo certinho no head e tals

Comment: Sampaio, e se ao invés do Jquery/JS eu enviasse ja pro meu mongoDB por angular nao seria mais facil? Se você viu o link do site da pra perceber mais ou menos que quero isso, mas como sou iniciante no assunto quis tentar por js e depois tentar mandar pro meu banco

Comment: eu realmente não sei, eu nunca usei mongoDB nem Angular, aí não posso te ajudar

Comment: Eu entrei nesse seu site e não dá esse erro! o que dá em sobre o bootstrap

Comment: Exato, nao aparece o erro! :/